# Remove everything after the fourth instance of a character

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a bulleted list in a cell and I want to only include the first 3 bullets in that cell.

As an example, I know I can use `=LEFT(P6,(FIND(CHAR(149),P6)+400))` to get the first 400 characters (the template I'm building this for can only handle 400 character max) but I want to stop just before the 4th bullet so that things are not cut off.

Is there a formula to use that only shows everything to the left of the 4th bullet. Its that nth number that I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(149),REPT(" ",LEN(A1)),4),LEN(A1)))
```